# CPU usage over 100% (Resource Monitor says 61325297%) after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows, cpu, windows-10, cpu-usage, windows-10-upgrade

Some time ago I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/966606/windows-10-keeps-showing-100-of-cpu-usage-no-matter-what) about a problem I found in my PC since I updated my Windows 7 to Windows 10 Pro x64, namely that my Task Manager was constantly showing 100% usage of my CPU even though I really wasn't using that much in my process + services.

Now I was looking back at that problem and decided to open the Windows program where we can see CPU usage in greater detail and what I found out was that that program was telling me the CPU usage is over 100%! (while my processes definitivaly weren't using not even 10%!)

Here is the print:

[image: Weird bug]

Now that clearly is a bug. How can I solve it? I'll try to find a new drive for my Intel Processor in the middle time but I really don't imagine an old drive could be the issue behind this.

**Note:** despite the title edit, it's interesting to mention that the value shown in Resource Monitor isn't fixed: it keeps changing (tremendously) each second in a way it seems that is printing random values.

Comment: Run ProcessExplorer and look if it also shows high CPU usage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: @Momergil: Might be best to merge this with your original question then close this one as they are almost certainly caused by the same issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981 No: Process Explorer shows the CPU usage normally as I would expect (e.g. now is around 7%). It seems it's a bug with Task Manager/Resource Monitor then.

Comment: report the issue to Microsoft via the feedback app.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thansk for the tip, I did that already (assuming we are talking about the same app!)

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly what happened to my computer. The blue circle next to the cursor kept on spinning while I was not doing anything. Then, eventually, I found many (several hundred and more) *Java(TM) Web Start Launcher* processes running according to Task Manager. Even though they took 0-1% CPU time each, they caused CPU and memory usage to reach 100%. Those processes are not listed at the top if you do sorting in Task Manager by CPU (but are easily noticeable since there a few hundred and more).

If this is your case, the following may help you as it did me:

1. Windows Key + R
2. Type `msconfig` and run it.
3. Go to the Service tab
4. Check *Hide all Microsoft Services*
5. Click *Disable all*
6. Go to the Startup tab
7. Disable all items
8. Optionally, in an administrative command prompt, run the following;

   `Dism  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
9. Reboot

After this work, my computer has been running fine for last two days. Then I went back to the `msconfig` and I turned on the services I really need such as OneDrive and Dropbox stuff.

Comment: Ben N, Thank you for your editing. Forwarding your corrections to me helped me a lot. I will be more careful in answering. Please bear with me that I am pretty new in this environment.

Comment: looks promising but didn't work