# CPU usage around 10.000.000+% on Windows Resource Monitor

Tags: display, cpu

I'm not finding a solution for this problem, my CPU is currently 10.000.000+% usage, frequency is always at 100%, all 8 cores is always at 100%, there's some problem in monitoring.

I made a screenshot for you to understand. All drivers are updated.

I don't know what else to do. The notebook is fast, the real CPU usage it's probably under 10%, but the monitor is crazy.

My specs: Intel Core i7 2630QM, 8GB DDR3 RAM, 240GB SSD Kingston

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: This reddit post relates the issue to an outdated BIOS on an AsRock motherboard: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3gj4j6/performance_monitor_says_cpu_usage_is_at_80/

Comment: Did you always have this problem?

Comment: But *be aware*: Updating BIOS is an advanced process and if you do it wrong you can break the whole system. Proceed with caution, read the motherboard manual before anything else.

Comment: Also refer to https://superuser.com/questions/982017/cpu-usage-over-100-resource-monitor-says-61325297-after-upgrading-to-windows

Comment: I already sarched for bios update, everything is updated included bios. I bought this notebook yesterday. I removed the 500GB HD and installed a 240GB SSD. I just realized this problem today! So I don't know if this problem is from now or not.

Comment: @spikey_richie, this question is exactly my problem, but nobody gave a solution for the problem, one guy gave one solution but it's for a problem of CPU usage, my CPU usage it's fine, my pc is as fast as it should be, my problem is another, it's with the Windows task manager measuring the CPU usage!

Answer (score 1):

I searched and found that this notebook model have this problem because of bios update lack. My bios is updated, but the last version don't support windows 10, and this problem when installing w10 is usual. it's a i7 2630QM, a great processor, but it's a Philco... I hope don't have any other problem 'cause of bios. I'll keep w10. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust Windows task manager, have a look at Sys Internals Process Explorer from here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: TY, I downloaded and my cpu usage is around 1,5% the problem is the Windows task manager, I usually use it, there's some way to reinstal it?

Comment: How does this answer the question?\

Comment: It doesn't, but it seemed better than just adding as a comment. I have no idea why Task Manager shows a billion %, but my link appears to have helped. Perhaps post an alternative answer if you have something more useful to provide...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/868576)

Comment: @Burgi - There isn't any information to include in the answer.  The suggestion is to verify the actual CPU usage with another program similar to Task Manager which would be considered an answer

Comment: @Burgi - I get that links become stale, but it's better than saying "just google process explorer" as that would return a vast number of search results, most of which won't be applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Ramhound